# How can an answer be added on a closed question

Tags: discussion

This  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373615/1-ask-what-is-the-temperature-in-degrees-celsius-and-assign-the-user-input-t/17373662#17373662)  was given on a closed question how can this happen?

Comment: Simple. Just use magic.

Comment: @jball, I thought jQuery was needed for this kind of thing.

Comment: Common misunderstanding. jQuery *is* magic.

Comment: @brasofilo jball. Behold! Magic! `a=$("[id*=answer]").last();b=a.clone();a.after(b)`